# @google-cloud/redis get and set not found

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, redis

I created Redis on Google Cloud Platform. My application is connecting. However, I cannot SET, GET, ON in the Client I created. What is the problem? Because it's not in it. So how am I going to manage?

```
const connectRedis = async () => {
    const { CloudRedisClient } = require('@google-cloud/redis')
    const thisClient = new CloudRedisClient()

    const formattedParent = thisClient.locationPath('project', 'location')

    const thisRequest = {
        parent: formattedParent
    }

    const thisResponse = (await thisClient.listInstances(thisRequest))[0]
}
```

thisClient.on || thisClient.on NOT FOUND.

Comment: I'm upvoting this. How do you get and set values using google cloud redis? Or do I not understand how this works? Note: The example provided is the only example in the documention.

Answer (score 0):

The @google-cloud/redis library is only for admin. It's not a client.

See discussion here:

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-redis/issues/386